# Solr client application AJAX-Solr error: NOT able to connect to my local Solr data collection

Tags: solr

I am working on the following Solr client application, but I always come across errors when trying to make step 1 work.

[AJAX-Solr Reuters Tutorial Example](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr/wiki/Reuters-tutorial)

I built my local Solr collection from reuter raw data downloaded from the tutorial link. I used Solr 9.4.0 to set up my local collection named "reuterdata", and tested it in the Solr Admin. The query and facet query work very well within my Solr Admin UI. But when I attempted to use the client-side AJAX-Solr program, it always had some error messages. I did change "solrUrl" in reuters.js to my local Solr path, "http://localhost:8983/solr/reuterdata/", and pointed my browser to "localpath/webproject/ajax-solr-master/examples/reuters/index.html", there was error saying:

"The resource from “http://localhost:8983/solr/reuterdata/select?facet=true&q=%3A&facet.field=topics&facet.field=organisations&facet.field=exchanges&facet.field=countryCodes&facet.limit=20&facet.mincount=1&f.topics.facet.limit=50&f.countryCodes.facet.limit=-1&facet.date=date&facet.date.start=1987-02-26T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%2FDAY&facet.date.end=1987-10-20T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%2FDAY%2B1DAY&facet.date.gap=%2B1DAY&json.nl=map&wt=json&json.wrf=jQuery172003692584046418779_1706919458200&_=1706919458231” was blocked due to MIME type (“application/json”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)."

"Loading failed for the with source “http://localhost:8983/solr/reuterdata/select?facet=true&q=%3A&facet.field=topics&facet.field=organisations&facet.field=exchanges&facet.field=countryCodes&facet.limit=20&facet.mincount=1&f.topics.facet.limit=50&f.countryCodes.facet.limit=-1&facet.date=date&facet.date.start=1987-02-26T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%2FDAY&facet.date.end=1987-10-20T00%3A00%3A00.000Z%2FDAY%2B1DAY&facet.date.gap=%2B1DAY&json.nl=map&wt=json&json.wrf=jQuery172003692584046418779_1706919458200&_=1706919458231”.

I understood that the error has something to do with the dataType definition in Manager.jquery.js. I changed the value of options from

"options = { dataType:'json'};"

to

"options = {dataType: 'application/javascript'};"

inside  executeRequest function. The error went away when I tested the index.html again, but new error,

"parsererror, Error: No conversion from text to application/javascript"

popped up. I googled this error for a whole day but couldn't figure out the solution. I have resolved the CORS error by adding some filter sections in my Solr server , web.xml, file as shown in the link, [Resolve Solr CORS error](https://laurenthinoul.com/how-to-enable-cors-in-solr/). I could not think of many more possible reasons for this error. Why does this simple first step not work? I knew the Solr version in this tutorial was Solr 4 or Solr 1.4. Does newest Solr 9.4.0 version not work with this AJAX-Solr application? Is there someone using the new Solr9.4.0 version to test this AJAX-Solr project?  Any replies will be appreciated.